# Using Different Character Encodings

Tags: c++, c, character-encoding

Recently, I have gotten interested in Text Encoding. As you know, there are many kinds of Text Encoding such as CRC949, UTF-8 and so on.

I am wondering how to express them properly. (To the screen and users.) I mean, they are different from each other. I remember there was particular way to express text accrording to encoding in C#.

Is it possible one can use just simple `printf()` in C to express string regardless of encoding? Does the compiler automatically do it?

Comment: Users really, really don't care. To them an `a` is an `a`, and all that binary gobbelygook behind the scenes should not concern them.

Comment: C has no notion of text encodings. `printf` simply writes bytes to the standard output. Once you understand the difference between a "byte" and a "unit of text", you should be able to appreciate that fact, and perhaps you'll be able to ask a more directed question. Just keep in mind that *there is no built-in text processing in either the C or the C++ standard libraries*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Joel Spolsky's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

From the article:

> We decided to do everything internally in UCS-2 (two byte) Unicode,
>   which is what Visual Basic, COM, and Windows NT/2000/XP use as their
>   native string type. In C++ code we just declare strings as wchar_t
>   ("wide char") instead of char and use the wcs functions instead of the
>   str functions (for example wcscat and wcslen instead of strcat and
>   strlen). To create a literal UCS-2 string in C code you just put an L
>   before it as so: L"Hello".

Comment: Wow! Lightening fast.. Thank you!!